# wpdb select from using array as search parameters

Tags: wpdb, array, select

Similar to how you can insert into an array using code such as

```
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, $inputs); //where inputs is an array
```

I want to do a sql select statement with code such as

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE " . $input);
```

where input could contain several search parameters. Is anything like this possible?

Comment: "Is anything like this possible" won't really bring up the best answers. Better would be to rethink your question and file an [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pass your information through `prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) as in this example from the Codex:

```
$metakey = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        array(
        10, 
        $metakey, 
        $metavalue
    ) 
) );
```

Your array should have the same number of elements as your query string has placeholders.

Comment: The question is asking about select.